# japanese's Special char encoding .Net 1.0

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net-1.0

I have a problem with ASP.NET and japanese.
My ASP.Net Web, SQLserver DB is encoded as JAPAN SHIFT_JIS,
but in japanese has about 45 special characters,
[enter link description here](http://www.tkmj.net/kanji-4.htm)

they are not the SHIFT-JIS,

```
* When inserted to DB "邰" is changed to "&#３７０４０;"
```

- In my C# code:

  ```
  string strHtmlDecode = Server.HtmlDecode("&#３７０４０;");
  this.txtName.Text = strHtmlDecode;
  ```

In the server side <.cs code file> when debuging return true character

```
"邰"
```

But the respond to client (HTML page) is not true. Because of page's encoding is shift-jis

=> solution for solve this problem?

=> Or how can I encode only "txtName" TextBox as utf-8 in a Shift-jis page?

Answer (score 0):

I not sure if your problem is the same as I had initially when I am doing inserting of Chinese characters. But you may try it by putting a N in front. Example

```
"insert into table_name(Text) values (N'" + textOfJapWord + " ')";
```

The column type for the "Text" is nvarchar. Probably might work?

Comment: "Respect". Thank for your answered. But i have tried insert that character by hand with true value and when view in my SHIFT-JIS page the character still not true. I think that SHIFT-JIS is japanese encoding but that character is cannot save as shift-jis

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to use newer .NET releases? .NET 4 or even .NET 2 should have better support on Japanese, so if this is a bug of .NET 1, it should already be fixed.

.NET 1.0 was end of support in 2009,

http://support.microsoft.com/lifecycle/search/Default.aspx?sort=PN&alpha=.NET+Framework

So you should never use it any more.

Comment: Thank for your reply, But my System is large and my customer still using it now. so that is difficult to upgrade it 2.0 or 4.0

Answer (score 0):

Try setting character set to utf-8:

```
  <head>
       <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8">
       <title>Page Title</title>
  </head>
```